# How to achieve the required execution order in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have this piece of code:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('appContoller', function($scope){

    var fun1 = function(){
        setTimeout(function() {console.log("aaaaa");}, 5000);
    }

    var fun2 = function(){
        console.log("bbbbb");
    }

    var myOrder = function(){
        fun1();
        fun2();
    }
});
```

Upon executing, the observed order is - first fun2, then fun1. How do I get them executed in the order fun1 first, then fun2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fun1` is doing a asynchronous job. So it let the code run and `fun2` is executed. If you want to wait for `fun1` end, you have multiple choices :

- Use a callback as parameter of `fun1`

  ```
  var fun1 = function(callback) {
      setTimeout(function() {console.log("aaaaa"); callback()}, 5000);
  };

  var fun2 = function(){
      console.log("bbbbb");
  }

  var myOrder = function(){
      fun1(fun2);
  }
  ```
- Use a promise

  ```
  angular.module('myApp').controller('appContoller', function($scope, $q){

      var fun1 = function(){
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          setTimeout(function() {console.log("aaaaa"); deferred.resolve()}, 5000);

          return deferred;
      }

      var fun2 = function(){
          console.log("bbbbb");
      }

      var myOrder = function(){
          fun1().then(fun2);
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: When I use Promise, I get to see an error, telling - **fun1(...).then is not a function**

Comment: Got it fixed by altering into: fun1().deferred.then(fun2);
t.y.

Comment: in the promise example fun1 should return deferred.promise;

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the setTimeOut for 5 sec, that's the reason the order behind that.
Still if you need the timeout function necessary then call function 2 inside timeout function.